# PHP: How print/echo accents/utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8

I got the basic structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

and the input:

```
<input type="text" name="var"/>
```

to get with:

```
$var = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $_POST['var']);
//or
$var = $_POST['var'];
```

and show like:

```
echo $var;
//or
print_r($var);
//or
print_r(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $var));
```

i try force a new header:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and with .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

and nothing works :(
The only things that appears is:
jos? instead josé

how solve it?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 5):

I think this would work for you:

```
echo utf8_encode($var);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your files are UTF-8 encoded.

You may also add character encoding to form tag

`<form action="demo_form.asp" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: I wish,  but i still don't have enough reputation. One day! :)